# What's the best way to debug a smart contract for testing purposes?

Tags: solidity, transactions, hardhat, contract-debugging, testing

I am getting the following error on a specific function when I try to send a transaction:

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data
    at SmartWallet._checkTokenType (contracts/extension/TokenBundle.sol:135)
    at SmartWallet._createBundle (contracts/extension/TokenBundle.sol:63)
    at SmartWallet._storeTokens (contracts/extension/TokenStore.sol:47)
    at SmartWallet.initialLoad (contracts/multiwrap/SmartWallet.sol:203)
    at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1815:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:504:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1522:18)
```

As you may see, there's not much information about what may be wrong rather than the line of code that is failing.

The problem I have is that if I do the same test using Remix, it works perfectly.

Is there a way to debug my smart contract to see exactly what the error is and what data is getting to that point of the execution?

Comment: If you are working with hardhat, you can put `console.log()` and check the values that might be at fault.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried with that and I am still not able to see the error. I am looking for a much more robust way of debugging, as you see in other programming languages.

Comment: I am nit sure if there is any, Though you can see here that your TokenBundle.sol contract is having the error at line 135. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Yes, I already know that and it is not helpful to me either.

Comment: If you have access to a node with tracing enabled, you can call (not send) it with tracing which provides a very, very detailed (far too detailed) execution log. Most public nodes seem to disable tracing because it takes computing power on the node.